# Sphinx +breathe HTML output is different than doxygen HTML output

Tags: python, c, xml, python-sphinx, doxygen

I need your help, please.

I created a documentation using Sphinx.

Inside this documentation, I needed to add another documentation about a C API. This API has its ready-generated doxygen documentation (html+latex+xml files)

I used the XML files generated by Doxygen and integrated them into my Sphinx project with the help of Breathe.

It worked and the two documentations are linked.

But the problem is that the sphinx HTML output (of the C API) is not as well structured as the doxygen HTML output.

Doxygen html output groups modules into one page and Data structures into another web page and the whole output is readable.

However, The sphinx html output puts all information on one page and the user can hardly read it.

**Note 1: Sphinx imitates the index.xml file's exact structure whether Doxygen puts it in a readable well-structured form.**

**Note 2: I only have one header file and I can't use multiple directories.**

What can I do to fix this issue?

Thank you

- I tried changing multiple elements in the Doxyfile configuration but it didn't work.

**Expected result**:
The Sphinx HTML output should have the same structure and pages as the Doxygen HTML output.

Comment: Always important which versions of doxygen, sphinx and breathe are you using?

Comment: Indeed. I am sorry. I used Doxygen 1.8.17 and Breathe 4.35.0.

Comment: Sphinx 's version is 4.5.0

Comment: I'm not a sphinx / breathe expert but are they (sphinx / breathe)  for sure using your doxygen 1.8.17 version or did they distribute a version themselves?

Comment: I am not sure how to answer you. But I have a requirement to work with that version of Doxygen. The Breathe version is the latest one and for the Sphinx version I just upgraded it to 7.2.6 and the same issue is still reproducible.

Comment: In the xml files generated for sphinx / breathe you will find the doxygen version used. I forgot to mention that doxygen 1.8.17 is already a bit older (December 27, 2019) the current doxygen version is 1.9.8. It might be that when the current sphinx / breathe get an old set op xml files it doesn't work properly.

Comment: I tried an alternative which is the directive:   .. autodoxygenfile:: . This directive automatically generates the HTML output from the header file (no need for XML files) The output is a bit better but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Instead of only using the directive doxygenindex, I used multiple directives for each element to be documented to fix this issue.

Foe example:

- doxygengroup
- doxygenstruct

**link :** https://breathe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/directives.html